# How to get file from a explicit ftp server to my server with php

Tags: php, ftp

I have server with explicit ftp server. I want to transfer a zip file from that server to my new server. But there are some error.FTP server is connected but the file is not transfer. The zip file is 118 MB size. Please Help me in it.

```
set_time_limit(0); //Unlimited max execution time

$remote_file = 'zipfile.zip';

/* FTP Account */
$ftp_host = 'example.com'; /* host */
$ftp_user_name = 'username@example.com'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'password'; /* password */


/* New file name and path for this file */
$local_file = 'zipfile.zip';


/* Connect using basic FTP */
$connect_it = ftp_ssl_connect( $ftp_host );
var_dump($connect_it);

if (@ftp_login($connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass))
{
  echo "Connection established.";
}
else
{
   echo "Couldn't establish a connection.";
}

/* Login to FTP */


/* Download $remote_file and save to $local_file */
var_dump(ftp_get( $connect_it, $local_file, $remote_file,FTP_BINARY ));
if ( ftp_get( $connect_it, $local_file, $remote_file,FTP_BINARY ) ) {
   echo "WOOT! Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
   echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
}

/* Close the connection */
ftp_close( $connect_it );
```

For testing purpose i can give you my ftp server credentials.
please comment me...

Comment: Start by removing the `@` from the beginning of `ftp_login()`.

Comment: Can you share the *actual* errors with us?

Comment: @Mike No Mike it is not working. The zip file size is 118 mb is it create the problem ????

Comment: @JayBlanchard By this code i am not getting any php error `ftp_login()` function shows that the connection is established but the file form the server to my another server  is not transferred. It shows `Doh! There was a problem`

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I get a warning `Warning: ftp_get(): Connecting to port 41465 in /home/bluinteri/public_html/filetransfer.php on line 38` after using `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045458/getting-warning-on-ftp-get-in-php

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think that's the problem may be. Thank you Jay for your support. Is there any other way to transfer file from one server to another. The zip file is so big (118mb) it takes lots of time to download and upload to other server. So can you please help with that jay.

Comment: FTP should work if configured properly. SCP could work too.